# Mocha With Selenium The Error: TypeError: Wait condition must be a promise-like object, function, or a Condition object

Tags: node.js, selenium, express, mocha.js

I'm new to Mocha and Selenium for testing an Express application. I have the following simple code, but I can't figure out what's going wrong.

```
describe("authenticateWithGoogle", function() {
    it("return a valid access token for our tests", function() {
        return new Promise( function(resolve) {

           var driver = new Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();
           driver.get('https://www.google.com');

           driver.wait("Google",5000).then( (quitDriver,handleFailure) => {
               console.log("wait over");
               assert.ok(true); 
           });

           resolve();
      }).then();
    });
});
```

I receive the follow error when I run 'mocha':

```
TypeError: Wait condition must be a promise-like object, function, or a Condition object
```

This occurs on the 'driver.wait' line in the code above. I really don't understand what the errors means.

Comment: what selenium library do you use?

Comment: selenium-webdriver npm 4.0.0-alpha.1

Comment: Maybe a related question is...is there an easier way to test OAuth?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried same selenium-webdriver 4.0.0 alpha.1 and it worked. 
Based on its example, it uses `async await` so I use same way.

```
const {Builder, By, Key, until} = require('selenium-webdriver');
const chai = require('chai');
const assert = chai.assert;

describe("authenticateWithGoogle", function() {
  it("return a valid access token for our tests", async function() {
    this.timeout(5000);

    let driver = await new Builder()
      .usingServer('http://localhost:4444/wd/hub')
      .forBrowser('chrome').build();

    try {
      await driver.get('http://www.google.com');
      await driver.wait(until.titleIs('Google'), 1000);
    } finally {
      assert.ok(true);
      await driver.quit();        
    }      
  });
});
```

My Setup:

- node 8.9
- selenium-standalone https://www.npmjs.com/package/selenium-standalone

Yes, for testing `oauth` you can create integration/e2e test for it. You're already in the right path.

Hope it helps